# Can "restrain" be used in a technical document?

Tags: verbs

I am trying to describe that a certain washer prevents **or** reduces the possibility of a bolt coming off.  In other words, I am trying to describe that the bolt usually stops a bolt from coming off, but may sometimes fail to do so.  That is, I don't want to vow that that washer always stops a bolt from coming off. If possible, I don't want to use the conjunction "**or**".  Could you advise me on my examples below:

> 1. This washer restrains a bolt from coming off.
> 2. This washer makes it unlikely that a bolt comes off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say

This washer **helps to keep** the bolt in place.

There is no guarantee there, and yet the purpose is explained. There is even an implication that the washer is not a perfect solution to the problem.

You could describe exactly what the washer does:

> This lock washer reduces  the effects of vibration, which can cause
>   the bolt to become loose.